# how to find linux-source-4.15.0 that i have downloaded?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

[image]

look at the picture.i think i have already downloaded linux-scorce-4.15.0,but how to find it.i have tried to open the Files to look for it,but it is nowhere.my question is about what i should do?it is so hard to submitted a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg -L linux-source-4.15.0
```

> -L, --listfiles package-name...
>
> List files installed to your system from package-name.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `data.tar` inside the `.deb` package you downloaded, then you can see its location.

[image: Sorry for cheating with 7z on Windows]

It puts the file under `/usr/src`.